# How to play .wav files with IE10?

Tags: html, flash, wav

I found a demo which works on Chrome, FF and Opera, but I cant get it to work on IE10.
http://www.phon.ucl.ac.uk/home/mark/audio/play9.htm

(IE10 does not support wav-files using the HTML5 audio-tag)

As I got several servers I would like to avoid a solution involving FFMPEG or server-plugin.

Anybody got a clue or tip about how to get to play a myfile.wav on on my webpage using IE10 ?

Answer (score 2):

Actually, I found out that I can use a simple `<embed>` tag.

```
<embed src="path/mywav.wav" autostart=false width=1 height=1 id="wavfile"
    enablejavascript="true">
```

Comment: Does this works for someone in IE11? not in mine :(

Answer (score -1):

Use the audio tag.

```
<audio width="300" height="48" controls="controls" autoplay="autoplay"><source src="http://test.com/test.wav" type="audio/webm"/>Your browser does not support HTML5 audio. Please update your browser to view this media content.</audio>
```

Comment: This works for Chrome and FF, but does'nt work on my IE10 for .wav files. I get "Error: Unsupported audio type or invalid file path".